# Ad DirectorySearcher limited to 1k rows

Tags: active-directory, ldap

IS there any way to get the AD searcher to return more than 1k rows, 
or to get it to return the results in 1k pages?

I need to do a test on all 45k users in our domain.

Code looks like this:

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher( entry );

```
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";             
    search.SizeLimit = 100000;//ignored if over 1000            

    foreach ( SearchResult result in search.FindAll() )
```

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PageSize` for results which may be more than 1000.
Example :

```
Use search.PageSize = 500;
```

[Source](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/04/29/the-finer-points-of-net-directoryservices/)